# Does Dependency Injection negatively affect the JVM's ability to optimize?

Tags: java, optimization, dynamic, jvm, guice

From my understanding in Java Optimization using Dynamic Recompilation, the JVM will continuously recompile byte-code sections based on real-time profiling, thus making it faster than even a well-written C-program. A comment was made by one of my colleagues that byte-code manipulation techniques such as Spring, Hibernate or AspectJ will mask out sections from being dynamically recompiled properly. Is that true?

I use Google Guice for Dependency Injection and I was wondering if potential loss of optimization would make it slower than by using plain traditional Java.

Comment: There are few confusions here: 1) When is Java Optimization the same as dynamic recompilation? 2) How does dynamic recompilation and dependency injection tie in with dynamic recompilation? 3) Can you provide a source to your "A comment was made" to substantiate your statement?

Comment: Why do you think that "byte-code manipulation techniques such as Spring, Hibernate or AspectJ" have any relation with dependency injection? - they don't, they're separate things

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.  In other words byte-code manipulation has no effect on dynamic recompilation.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, Spring will use java proxies (java.lang.reflect.Proxy) for features such as @Cache,... whenever an interface is available, and regular reflection for dependency injection (it will call the setXxx when property xxx is @Autowired annotated).

Even when bytecode manipulation is required, this bytecode is stored in one of the application ClassLoader, and therefore is available for the JVM to optimize. I cannot see how this would be different from some regular code.